# Is my Android device infected with a virus?

Tags: android, virus

I don't know if my device has a virus, but I will describe the symptoms:

1. My device suddenly reduces its performance, applications are lagging and reacting slowly while RAM is still free.
2. When I am googling using the web browser, it displays an error then immediately redirects to the result, or the web browser doesn't return a result altogether.
3. The ram consumption rises very fast
4. Many times the audio record folder is written into. Two fake audio files appear there. Those can't be played and their size reached 4GB.
5. Once, an audio file has been changed to 3gpp format without me doing it.

Are those symptoms related to any known Android virus?

Comment: yes all of these things could easily be a virus

Comment: the anti virus and trojan programs can't find any really malicious codes.i had deleted all of these files,i also change the dns.this is too hard to stop.

Comment: reset to factory defaults

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you have been infected by some sort of malware.
We could talk about all the things that you pointed out, but that won't change the fact that you are most likely infected, and your personal data could be at risk.

My recommendation:

Factory reset your android device and move on. (Don't save anything from your phone at this point, some malware change files with malicious code, so forget about those (pictures, music, any sort of files))